# Can I get Selenium WebDriver to use an existing Safari browser session?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to bypass an issue where I have an accept screen which once i've pressed it doesn't come back up unless you use a new browser session, i therefore want to get my selenium script to just use the existing profile/browser session, but struggling to find the code to do it, any help at all is greatly appreciated!

I've tried passing in the cookie but that's not worked unfortunately and my selenium script can't see the frame that the accept button is on :(

Answer (score 0):

**It's officially not supported.**

*However, there is some working code which claims to support this:, Also this is in java I am sure you can make in your desire language*

https://web.archive.org/web/20171214043703/http://tarunlalwani.com/post/reusing-existing-browser-session-selenium-java/

Comment: That solution is for Chrome in the first loop